# Angular focus on formcontrol

Tags: forms, focus, angular6

I have the following input:

```
 <input
                #participantInput="ngModel"
                id="participantInput"                  
                pattern="^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$"
                class="cell small-7"
                placeholder="John.Doe@gmail.com"
                [(ngModel)]="newParticipantMail"
                (keyup.enter)="addParticipant()"
                style="height:10%;">
```

Due to the `#participantInput="ngModel"`

I'm not able to retrieve the elementRef like :

```
@ViewChild('participantInput') participantInput: ElementRef;
```

So, how can I set the focus on that field?

Comment: i think you should not set #participantInput="ngModel", only #participantInput

Comment: @firegloves yes but then I'm not able to validate the input anymore with participantInput.invalid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add another template variable like this:

```
 <input
            #participantInput="ngModel"
            #participantRef
            id="participantInput"                  
            pattern="^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$"
            class="cell small-7"
            placeholder="John.Doe@gmail.com"
            [(ngModel)]="newParticipantMail"
            (keyup.enter)="addParticipant()"
            style="height:10%;">
```

Then you can access it into your component

```
@ViewChild('participantRef') participantRef: ElementRef;
```

Obviously you must wait for view initialization, for example implementing `AfterViewInit` interface

Comment: many thanks, solution seems so simple... I was not aware you can define multiple variables on the same html tag.

Comment: yeah, it is a bit confusing, but pondering well they are only variables and we are binding them to different things